# Why doesn't my "IF" statement work? (Works if commented out)

Tags: javascript

So I'm new to jQuery, and I can't figure out why my IF statement isn't working, although code works when I comment out the IF. Please help me...Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("tr.anon").hide();
$("#hideID").change(function(){
//    IF ($("#hideID option[value='no']").text()){
      $("tr.anon").show();
//      alert($this).find("option:selected").text()+' clicked!');
//  }ELSE{
//    $("tr.anon").hide();
//  }
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Would you like to remain anonymous?&nbsp;<select id="hideID">
<option value="yes">Yes</option>
<option value="no">No</option>
</select></p>
<table border="1px">
<tr class="anon">
<td>Enter your name:</td>
<td><input class="field2" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the quick feedback... I have adjusted my code to the following but it still is not working.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("tr.anon").hide();
    $("#hideID").change(function(){
//      if ($("#hideID option[value='no']").text()){
        $("tr.anon").show();
//        alert(#hideID).find("option:selected").text()+' clicked!');
//    }else{
//      $("tr.anon").hide();
//    }
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Would you like to remain anonymous?&nbsp;
<select  id="hideID">
<option value="yes">Yes</option>
<option value="no">No</option>
</select></p>
<table border="1px">
<tr class="anon">
<td>Enter your name:</td>
<td><input class="field2" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive - use `if`, `else`, etc.

Comment: Learn to appreciate the JavaScript errors reported by the browser. This is a SyntaxError, in particular.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Change to value==='no'. = is for assignment, and == and === are comparison.

Comment: The `=` is inside of the [Attribute equals value selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), so in this case a single `=` is appropriate.

Comment: Why was this accepted? It's quite definitely wrong -- it looks like Michael C Gates' answer actually helped you; that one should have been accepted if it worked.

Comment: I think he meant to mark my other answer as correct? It's a few answers down.

Answer (score 3):

You should not use CAPS for `IF` and `ELSE`!!!

Answer (score 1):

`if` and `else` must be lower-case. Javascript is case-sensitive.

Also, I don't think the `if` clause here is doing what you want. You are testing the truthiness of `#hideID option[value='no']`, which will always evaluate to true. I think you really want to check whether the 'no' value is selected. Also, you are simply toggling visibility, so jQuery's [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method would be more appropriate here.

Try this instead:

```
$('tr.anon').toggle( $("#hideID option:selected").val() === "no" );
```

Comment: Adam, I don't think i am following... where is the condition being tested?

Comment: Aah. I see .toggle() can be used to show/hide you don't have to know what state the control is in to use it. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @jg100309 correct, `.toggle()` accepts a boolean and triggers `.show()` or `.hide()`

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you aren't writing your 'if...else' statement in caps!

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is case sensitive, your `if` and `else` should be lowercase.

Also, you're checking whether `$("#hideID option[value='no']").text()` is truthy or not. If the text is anything other than an empty string you will go down the true path, is this your intention?

Comment: you are coprrect, that wasn't what I wanted to do. My intention was to get the selected value.

Comment: oops. i wanted to test if the selected value of the drop-down is 'no', and if it is, then show the text box

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's try this... I fixed the script to work. You can see the changes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("tr.anon").hide();
$("#hideID").change(function(){
    if ($("#hideID").val()=="no"){
        $("tr.anon").show();
        alert($(this).find("option:selected").text() + ' clicked!');
    } else {
        $("tr.anon").hide();
                    $("#textFieldID").val("");
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, but the alert line is really just me playing around, so I tested out your suggestion without it, but I'm afraid that when i changed the value of the dd the textbox didn't appear.

Comment: oops my bad- i had a typo and forgot to include val's (). fixed it and it works wonderfully. Thanks I appreciate everyone's assistance!

Comment: I know, but it wasn't written correctly. You were doing alert($this)., which would alert "$this", which has two problems: $this doesn't exist, and alert(code goes here). I added code to clear the value of the text box after change.

Answer (score 0):

Since you just have the two values, you can use this:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/eqxCa/

Script:

```
$( 'tr.anon' ).hide();
$( '#hideID' ).change( function() { $( 'tr.anon' ).toggle(); } );
```